# SQL Server Management Studio - PRINT from trigger not showing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, printing, triggers

I've confused with behavior of Management Studio. I've created a simple trigger for testing (UPDATE action), it should show message (print) to Messages Tab, but no Messages Tab is appear and I can't see any output. If I execute any other query it is ok I could see result tab and messages Tab. The trigger is works itself (data is changing).

Here is my code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger1]
ON [dbo].[TestTable]
FOR UPDATE
AS
    PRINT ('YAHOOOOO!!!') /* can't see this message */
    UPDATE TestTable
    SET    TestData = 'testitem'
    WHERE  (TestId = 2)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are actually executing an `UPDATE` statement that would fire the trigger? The one shown in the question is part of the trigger definition not a separate statement. That looks like an error. You need a `GO` after the `PRINT` statement so that is a separate batch.

Comment: Hi Martin! Thank for response. To test it i just click on TestTable -> Edit Top 200 Rows and then manualy change value in row #10 f.e. and immediately row #2 change it TestData column value to 'Anna', so i think trigger is work, sorry i'am very newbie

Comment: If you are doing it in the graphical tools in SSMS it probably simply doesn't display these non error messages anywhere. Try running an `UPDATE` statement from a new query window instead of using the UI editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 problems

1. Your trigger will cause a "too many recursions" error because it tries to update the table (within trigger) which calls the trigger again, which then tries to update the table, then calls the trigger... ad infinitum (in theory). In practice, SQL Server kills it after detecting the error.
2. The "Edit Top 200 rows" is a special feature that has its own messages window, so you cannot see any output.  You need to run your code in a new Query window.

In a new query window, redefine the trigger as follows:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger1]
ON [dbo].[TestTable]
FOR UPDATE
AS
    PRINT 'YAHOOOOO!!!'; /* can't see this message */
GO
```

Then, run this UPDATE statement on its own.

```
UPDATE TestTable
SET    TestData = 'testitem'
WHERE  TestId = 2;
```

*Note: Drop the extraneous brackets.*

Comment: It depends on the setting for [`RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190739.aspx) whether it will bail out (after 32 calls) or simply not call the trigger. Either way that code in a trigger doesn't make any sense.

Comment: No it doesn't, which is I asked for OP to redefine the trigger

Comment: Oh sorry guys my bad, now i've understood that PRINT and UPDATE statements is a different parts, UPDATE actually fires the trigger